# Can't run "cd" command in PHP shell_exec()

Tags: php

I recently got my laptop with Apache setup on my university's Ethernet connection. Now I can connect to my computer from anywhere as long as I have either the IP address or host name (which I can choose). Now I want to create a Web-based command prompt that will let me run commands on my laptop from any device.

One problem is that I can't run the "cd" command. I have my PHP script setup so it can run a series of commands delimited by a newline character. So I run "cd ../" and then "pwd" but it's still in the root directory of my Web app. How do I fix this?

Comment: Although I didn't downvote myself, I would assume it happened because it's an extremely insecure workaround for a problem that was solved long ago: just use SSH. SSH is available on Mac, Android, Linux, BSD … and if you're on Windows, use putty, it's a tiny download.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you have to change the directory of the current process/script. You do this with [`chdir`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php). Then you can run `shell_exec`.

I assume you realize the severe security concerns your solution creates...

Comment: Thank you for answering the question while also raising the security concerns.  Too often people will just say "it's insecure, don't do it" without actually helping.  This was a refreshing change from that.

Answer (score 13):

If you do this:

```
 shell_exec("cd ..");
 shell_exec("pwd");
```

Then the second command will be executed with a new shell, which has the same starting directory as the first had, because it's a subprocess of the current PHP.

The changing of the current directory with the first shell exec won't last to the second one. Such a series of depended shell commands only works by executing all at once:

```
 shell_exec("cd .. ; pwd");
```

Comment: With a popen is it possible to open /bin/bash and send with fwrite commands ?