# Laravel/Composer - run composer update in sub folder application

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I want to create an application which contains 2 sub applications (Laravel). Once I've ran composer update on the top level application I want to run composer update on the sub applications automatically using composer "scripts". Can this be accomplished?

Ive tried adding something like:

```
"post-update-cmd": [
    "cd front",
    "~/composer.phar update",
    "cd ../back",
    "~/composer.phar update"
],
```

but obviously this doesn't work. Any ideas?

regards

Answer (score 0):

found the answer on this post: [Can't run "cd" command in PHP shell_exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771913/cant-run-cd-command-in-php-shell-exec)

```
"post-update-cmd": [
    "cd ./front ; ~/composer.phar update",
    "cd ./back ; ~/composer.phar update"
]
```